# Set X Y Coordinates in QGraphicsItem QT

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem, qapplication

To determine the coordinates of an object with Qapplication and QGraphicsItem Library,Usually used `setPos` and `setPos(mapToParent(yvelocity,-xvelocity))`.The problem with these commands is that they determine the "speed" of the object move(Not their X Y Coordinates!).
So by what Command I can give X & Y inputs and the object goes to those coordinates?
thanks in advance.

Comment: You could retrieve the current position (with [pos()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#pos)) and set the new position by adding `yvelocity` and `-xvelocity` to that respectively.

Comment: @Scheff, How is this done? Can you explain with an example and write Commands?

Comment: Something like `setPos(pos() + mapToParent(yvelocity,-xvelocity))`. Although `pos()` returns [QPointF](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointf.html), you may apply the `operator+`. - There is a suitable overload. Are you familiar a bit with vector algebra?

Comment: @Scheff, Yes, Thanks a lot, I will test this.

Comment: @Scheff, This is not possible.My Codes  `QPointF location =this->pos(); xvelocity = .6*cos(head); yvelocity =.6*sin(head); setPos(location + mapToParent(yvelocity,-xvelocity));`with this codes output is: 

QPointF(3.37262,-2.16553)
QPointF(7.04894,-4.19207)
QPointF(7510.47,-4139.51)
QPointF(961316,-529883)
QPointF(1.92263e+06,-1.05977e+06)
 QPointF(7.8751e+09,-4.3408e+09)
QPointF(1.57502e+10,-8.6816e+09)
QPointF(3.15004e+10,-1.73632e+10)
&........

Comment: The `mapToParent()` is IMHO the wrong part in this. Sorry, I didn't think about this before but updated my answer respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In my comment I gave the recommendation:

> Something like `setPos(pos() + mapToParent(yvelocity,-xvelocity))`. Although `pos()` returns [QPointF](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointf.html), you may apply the `operator+`. - There is a suitable overload.

While thinking twice, I struggled over `mapToParent()` which appears wrong to me.

According to the OP, the velocity describes a *direction*. The `mapToParent()` is dedicated to translate a local *position* to a *position* in parents coordinate system.

> [**QPointF QGraphicsItem::mapToParent(const QPointF &point) const**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#mapToParent)
>
> Maps the point *point*, which is in this item's coordinate system, to its parent's coordinate system, and returns the mapped coordinate. If the item has no parent, *point* will be mapped to the scene's coordinate system.

So, the better recommendation might be:

```
setPos(pos() + QPointF(yvelocity,-xvelocity));
```

---

I made an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) `testQGraphicsItemSetPos.cc` to demonstrate this:

```
// Qt header:
#include <QtWidgets>

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup data
  QGraphicsScene qGScene;
  QImage qImg("smiley.png");
  QGraphicsPixmapItem qGItemImg(QPixmap::fromImage(qImg));
  qGScene.addItem(&qGItemImg);
  const qreal v = 2.0;
  qreal xVel = 0.0, yVel = 0.0;
  // setup GUI
  QWidget qWinMain;
  qWinMain.resize(320, 200);
  qWinMain.setWindowTitle("QGraphicsView - Move Item");
  QVBoxLayout qVBox;
  QGraphicsView qGView;
  qGView.setScene(&qGScene);
  qVBox.addWidget(&qGView, 1);
  qWinMain.setLayout(&qVBox);
  qWinMain.show();
  // timer for periodic update
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;
  QTime qTime(0, 0);
  QTimer qTimerAnim;
  qTimerAnim.setInterval(50ms);
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qTimerAnim, &QTimer::timeout,
    [&]() {
      // change velocity xVel and yVel alternating in range [-1, 1]
      const qreal t = 0.001 * qTime.elapsed(); // t in seconds
      xVel = v * std::sin(t); yVel = v * std::cos(t);
      // apply current velocity to move item
      qGItemImg.setPos(qGItemImg.pos() + QPointF(xVel, yVel));
    });
  // runtime loop
  qTimerAnim.start();
  return app.exec();
}
```

and a `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(QGraphicsItemSetPos)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

find_package(Qt5Widgets CONFIG REQUIRED)

include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")

add_executable(testQGraphicsItemSetPos testQGraphicsItemSetPos.cc)

target_link_libraries(testQGraphicsItemSetPos Qt5::Widgets)
```

with which I built and started the sample in VS2017:

[image: snapshot of testQGraphicsItemSetPos.exe (animated)]